# How to add keyboard shortcuts in python

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to add keyboard shortcuts in my program. For e.g. if someone typed ctrl+D, my program should print `Hello World`. So how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pynput` module to listen to mouse and key events

```
from pynput import keyboard

# The key combination to check
COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')}
]

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()

def execute():
    print ("Do Something")

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```